# How to split multiple polygon layer into multiple layers by vertices parts?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, editing, vertices

I have a layer in Arcmap 10 that was brought over from Auto CAD (layer A).  This layer has multiple polygon shapes.  I need to split these shapes from layer A, and place them into their own layers.  When I brought over the layer from Auto CAD, it put all the polygons into one shape.  So when I go to select one in editing, it selects them all.  When I look at editing the vertices I can see each one is a separate part.  Is there a way to split these parts apart to place into their own layers?[image: Note that there is only one shape in the table, and each part is linked to a specific polygon]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **[Multipart To Singlepart](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003r000000)** tool explodes multipart features, creating a new feature class of single part features.